# BFG cleaner did not delete files from all branches

Tags: git, github, bfg-repo-cleaner

I used the following command:

```
java -jar bfg-1.13.0.jar --delete-files "settings.xml"
```

And the settings.xml file was correctly removed from the master branch. The file is deleted and is even omitted when looking at old commits, which is just what I wanted.

However, if I look in other branches, I still see the settings.xml there. I thought maybe I needed to merge the master branch into these others branches, so I did that, but the file still exists in those other branches.

Does anyone know why only the master branch was cleaned?